# Only apply redirect to certain Submit Buttons with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if this is possible. I just want to check. Some advice will really help thank you.
I want to redirect all my forms to a thank you page using a class.

This is the code I wrote.

```
if ($(".vfb_redirect")[0]){ 
    window.location = "https://webfootprint.co.za/thank-you";
}
```

But I know this is going to apply to all Submit buttons if the class .vfb_redirect exists on the page which becomes a problem if I want to add a different submit button to my page. 
(2 submit buttons on one page.)

What I want to do is to apply the redirect to only the Submit button with the class .vfb_redirect.

Please, can someone point me in the right direction on how I can achieve this?

I need it to be a class because I'm using a paid plugin that only lets me add a class to my form fields.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: How about `if ($(".vfb_redirect")[0] && theRightSubmitButtonBeClicked){ ...`

Comment: Use form element's 'action' to redirect you to the url, and give your submit button type = 'submit'. It will do the thing for you.
Refer this link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you not define a method inside your button which is responsible for redirect?

```js
function redirect(){
    window.location = "https://example.com/";
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" onclick="redirect()">Submit</button>
```

This way only this button will do the redirect for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery `click()` Method

```js
$(".vfb_redirect").click(function(){
    window.location = "https://example.com/";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" class="vfb_redirect">Submit</button>
```

In case of multiple buttons

```js
function redirect(){
   window.location = "https://example.com/";
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="vfb_redirect" onclick="redirect(this)">Submit</button>
```

Comment: There can be more than one buttons with the same class.

Comment: @Harman he said 'only the Submit button with the class .vfb_redirect.'

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating a submit, create a button that calls a function, change the submit url and then call the js submit:

```
<script>
    function submitForm(id){
        if (id === 1)
            document.getElementById("myForm").target = "URL1";
        else
            document.getElementById("myForm").target = "URL2";

        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
</script>
```

and then your buttons:

```
<input type="button" onclick="submitForm(1) value="Button 1" />
<input type="button" onclick="submitForm(2) value="Button 2" />
```